# Use `known-hosts-files` for `zsh` ssh command completion

Tags: mac-osx, zsh

**This question was [originally asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76475108/7441353), which is incorrect. As I was not able to (get it) moved to serverfault, I am re-asking it.**

I am trying to configure tab completion for the `ssh` command in `zsh` to use an *additional* `known_hosts` file (which not located in `~/.ssh`). By additional I mean I still want to use the "default" `known_hosts` file.

Currently, when I hit `TAB` after `ssh`, I get a list of hosts which seems to come from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and (probably) `/etc/hosts`. I would like to also get the hosts listed in `~/other/path/known_hosts`.

I found a lot of material online, but somehow I cannot wrap my head around this one. The [zsh webiste](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) for example lists a `style` called `known-hosts-files` which sounds **very** promising. Also when I [see how it is used](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Completion/Unix/Type/_hosts#L39) it seems quite to the point.

But I cannot figure out how to use `known-hosts-files`.

I tried, for example, the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:*' known-hosts-files '~/other/path/known_hosts'
```

and many variations of it to no avail.

For good measure I have also added (in my `.zshrc`):

```
zstyle ":completion:*:commands" rehash 1
```

but this did not change anything.

There is [an older answer](https://serverfault.com/a/170481) here on serverfault and [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377765)) tackling the same question, but I do not fully understand them and it *seems* that `known-hosts-files` should do exactly what I want?

I also use Oh-my-zsh, if that matters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found the culprit: quotes.

When setting `known-hosts-files` to just a single file (like in my example), the quotes can be used, but *not with `~`*!

Adding this to `.zshrc` works as intended (macOS):

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:*' known-hosts-files 'Users/<username>/other/path/known_hosts'
```

In hindsight it seems reasonable: to set `known-hosts-files` to a *list* of files, **do not use quotes at all** (`~` is then OK to use again).

So the following works:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:*' known-hosts-files /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/other/path/known_hosts
```

This seems to be related to the fact that the shell is interpreting the quoted text as a literal single string... Naturally...